# QGIS 3x switching off label callouts

Tags: qgis, labeling

I need my label callouts switching off.

Basically I know how to do it. I am clicking on the label info ("Change label properties" I the main toolbar, then just switching off "Show callout".

[image]

The problem is twofold.
1 - I have to do it one by one
2 - If I switch it off, I am losing all the amendments done before (switching off brings my label back to beginning view) and I have to redo my changes.

Is there any change to switch label callouts for a whole defined text rule?

Comment: You could change the style of the whole rule in the layer properties?

Comment: Yes, thanks. I went to Callouts section and deactivated "Draw callout".

Comment: You're welcome. If I may be so bold: I think you could quite profit from a bit of interaction with a senior GIS-user. You often seem to do easy things in a complicated way. At our company we try to do this by seating the senior/"power" users next to the less experienced ones once in a while for a few days to enhance the exchange of best practice and new ideas.